# Custom django authentication backend doesn't log user in first time, but works second time

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

So I'm using Rdio to login and create users, and wrote a backend to handle its oauth. The first time you try to sign in using Rdio, it creates a user and an attached Rdio user, but it doesn't create a session and return the session cookie.

The flow is like any oauth2 flow: you press a button on my app, it redirects w/ get params to Rdio, and Rdio calls a callback view on my app (along with a code in the GET params). In that callback view, I call authenticate:

```
class RdioCallbackView(View):
def get(self, request):
    """ here, you need to create and auth a django user and create and tie the rdio user's stuff to it """
    if request.user.is_authenticated() == False:
        try:
            rdio_code = request.GET['code']
        except KeyError:
            return redirect(reverse('login'))
        # authenticate
        user = auth.authenticate(rdio_code=rdio_code)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
        else:
            return render(request, 'home/login.html', {'rdio_url': create_rdio_auth_url(), 'message': "That code didn't seem to work"})
    else:
        # user exists!
        user = request.user
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('the-next-view'))
```

The custom auth backend looks like this:

```
class RdioBackend(object):
def authenticate(self, rdio_code=None):
    token_info = exchange_rdio_code(rdio_code)
    try:
        access_token = token_info['access_token']
        refresh_token = token_info['refresh_token']
    except KeyError:
        return None
    except TypeError:
        # the code was probably already used.
        return None

    rdio_user_dict = get_rdio_user_for_access_token(access_token)
    rdio_key = rdio_user_dict['key']

    try:
        rdio_user = RdioUser.objects.get(rdio_id=rdio_key)
        rdio_user.access_token = access_token
        rdio_user.refresh_token = refresh_token
        rdio_user.save()
        user = rdio_user.user
    except RdioUser.DoesNotExist:
        user = User.objects.create(username=rdio_key)
        user.set_unusable_password()
        rdio_user = RdioUser.objects.create(
            rdio_id = rdio_key,
            access_token = access_token,
            refresh_token = token_info['refresh_token'],
            user = user,
            )
    return user

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

And that's where things get weird. It doesn't seem to make a new Session object, and definitely doesn't return a session cookie. However, when I go back and do the Rdio login again for a second time, it returns a session cookie, makes the session on the backend, and login and auth work perfectly.

And I think my AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS settings is right:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'appname.backend.RdioBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Edit: More possibly relevant info:
The views that it's redirecting to have a LoginRequiredMixin:

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
@classmethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
    return login_required(view)
```

And in RdioCallbackView, when I change the final line from `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('the-next-view'))` to instead just serve the template directly with `return render(request, 'path/to.html', param_dict)`, it does serve the cookie and make a sessionid, but then it deletes it from the DB and from the browser the moment I navigate away from that screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the dumbest bug ever. It turns out that if you create a user without a password, you don't need to call `user.set_unusable_password()`. And if you do call `user.set_unusable_password()`, it somehow messes with any auth you do (even AFTER you call that).

So to fix this, I just got rid of the call to `user.set_unusable_password()` in my custom django auth backend.